# Change access policy of existing Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to setup Access Policy for existing Azure Key Vault using Fluent Managment

I can define access policy during creation and access them after it, but I can't find any method to alter it later.
I want to add `Set` permission, add some secrets, and revoke it.

```
 _azure.Vaults.Define(name)
                    .WithRegion(group.Region)
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup(group)
                    .DefineAccessPolicy()
                        .ForServicePrincipal(principalName)
                        .AllowSecretPermissions(secretPermissions)
                        .Attach()
                    .CreateAsync()

 appVault.AccessPolicies.?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to update  existing keyvault access policies.

In C# we can use the [keyvault nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault) and the [Keyvaultmanagementclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-dotnet) class to manage azure keyvault.

We can also update the keyvault access policies using Powershell commandlet S[et-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/set-azurermkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azurermps-6.0.0)

And the same can be achieved of course using Azure RM rest APIs . Vaults-[Update access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/updateaccesspolicy).